# How to use reledmac in twocolumn document (with ltxgrid)

Tags: footnotes, two-column, reledmac, ltxgrid

I'm trying to typeset footnotes with the excellent `reledmac` package in a two-columned document that uses the `ltxgrid` package from revtex.

In the following MWE, it appears that the two packages play together well, BUT for the simple fact that the footnotes do not appear. See this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{latin}

\RequirePackage[series={T}]{reledmac}
\RequirePackage{ltxgrid}

\arrangementX[T]{twocol}
\let\footnote\footnoteT % Toggle this line to see the footnotes as 
            % ltxgrid would typeset them without reledmac!

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter 
\chapter{Some Chapter Headline}

\twocolumngrid

\lipsum*[3]\footnote{Fn 1 \lipsum[3]}

\lipsum*[3]\footnote{Fn 2}

\lipsum*[3]\footnote{Fn 3}

\lipsum*[3]\footnote{Fn 4}

\lipsum*[5]\footnote{Fn 5}

\onecolumngrid
\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems that the vertical room for the footnotes is saved but then the footnote register is not printed and instead the columns are vertically stretched over the whole page. (You can compare by commenting out the `\let\footnote\footnoteT` line in which case the footnotes appear but as typeset by `ltxgrid`, which is not my goal.)

Is there any way I can "trigger" the footnote output routine of `reledmac` at the right point by patching some part of `ltxgrid`? 
Or do you have any other idea?

addendum: As I notice, the problem is not specific to using `\twocolumngrid`. It would also appear in `\onecolumngrid`.

Comment: Well, I have looked on ltxgrid.sty, and he made a lot of with inserts, and it will be hard for me to make it compatible. But globally, the idea woul be to add \footinsT when ltxgrid.sty have \footins. I think you could join the ltxgrid.sty author, to ask him to add "hook" where package which manage more than one level of footnote could insert there own footnote.